# Is this piecewise function differentiable at $x = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

### The question:

I am new here, so excuse if I am messing something up. Now I have a question about this piecewise function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2sin\frac{1}{x}, &\text {if $x$  ≠ 0} \\ 0, &\text{if $x$ = 0} \end{cases}$$

### What I did:

---

so what I did was, by using the derivative's definition and substituting 0 as x I came to this final conclusion:

$$f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0}hsin\frac{1}{h}$$

I looked into integrating the derivative I got and the function into [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lqju7gmku2) aaaand, I am confused now as if it is differentiable or not because based on the graph it doesn't look like, from the squeeze theorem we get 0, and then does that mean that it is differentiable at 0 and that it will be also 0 when we look for f(0)?

any insight is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Here's one big improvement you can make to your post: [make your question visible](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992); "Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see your question, it should be immediately visible after clicking on your title."

Comment: In the graph you linked on Desmos, it's clear that $h\sin\frac{1}{h}\to 0$ as $h\to 0$. What about that graph makes you think the limit doesn't exist or that the function isn't differentiable at zero?

Comment: Note that $x\sin\frac{1}{x}$ is _not_ differentiable at 0 - but it doesn't have to be. We just need its _limit_ at 0 to exist.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for your feedback! I will work on editing it.

Comment: @BrennanVincent so at that point, the limit exists? when I looked at both right and left side, I probably made a mistake which showed me different values of that sort. so the limit does exist, but why isn't it differentiable at 0?

Comment: The simplest way to put it is that the closer $h$ gets to zero, the closer $h\sin\frac{1}{h}$ gets to zero. That's what the concept of limit means.

To be clear, $x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$ is indeed differentiable at zero, because the limit of the difference quotient $h\sin\frac{1}{h}$ exists. I'm just saying that _that_ function (i.e., $x\sin\frac{1}{x}$), which you have also plotted, _isn't_ differentiable, which might be what's confusing you. (Its difference quotient is $\sin\frac{1}{h}$ which does not approach any limit as $h\to 0$).

Comment: oh I got it now! Thank you for your time and descriptive answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right up to $$f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} h\sin \frac{1}{h}.$$

Now since the sine function is bounded (to wit, $-1 \leq \sin t \leq 1$ for all $t$), we have $$\left|h\sin\frac{1}{h}\right| \leq |h|,$$ which clearly goes to $0$ as $h$ does. Thus $$f'(0) = 0.$$